# Alfresco: change "Start Workflow" button text

Tags: javascript, button, alfresco

I have developed a custom workflow in Alfresco that starts with a form. I need to change the "Start Workflow" button to say "Submit". I have located the line in the **start-workflow.get.js** file which accomplishes this:

```
submitButtonMessageKey : "button.startWorkflow"
```

However, when I attempt to override this is in my .properties files on both the repository and share sides, the change is not reflected. I have tried the following:

```
button.startWorkflow=Submit
myWorkflow.button.startWorkflow=Submit
myWorkflow.workflow.button.startWorkflow=Submit
```

What correct syntax or implementation must I follow to successfully change the text?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to override message using

```
button.startWorkflow=Submit
```

Only thing is you need to make sure file which you are trying to override is loaded properly and overriding existing one.

Other option is to override webscript's controller which will point to new lable from your new message bundle file. you need to create exactly same folder structure under web-extension and place those files @ that location.

Best way is to use extension mechanism to override existing webscript.

Comment: Would a share context file with a bean pointing to its location properly override it? And if so, what class and/or parent would that require?